# Computer(Windows 10) suddenly disconnected from the internet

Tags: windows-10, router, dns, home-networking

UPDATE: booting into safe mode network fixes it. But when I go back to regular mode its broken again.

While I was browsing reddit. My browser(Chrome), suddenly said that I have no internet connection.

My steam disconnected, can't ping Google. My network icon has that yellow triangle thing on my taskbar

I checked my phone, It had internet, my brother was currently watching Netflix on TV in the living room, the house has internet.

So I logged into my router, pc can connect to router settings via web browser. I am connected via Ethernet cable. I tried to use the troubleshoot tool in windows network and internet settings.

It said the DNS server isn't responding.

I tried to ipconfig release, renew, flushdns, winsock reset then restart pc
Still can't connect.

Tried setting preferred dns from auto to 8.8.8.8 did not work

Any tips?

Comment: how about re-installing the wifi driver?

Comment: Reinstalling driver did not work. BTW it's not wifi, it's Ethernet cable

Comment: Is windows updates installed? Sometimes it affect the newtork interface

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that your network works fine in SafeMode, this indicates there is some software/driver that is causing the issue.

- Additional testing could be useful

  - Ping 8.8.8.8, see if your computer is able to connect to the internet but is lacking DNS services
  - Run a "NSLookup google.com", see if that resolves and what kind of information you get back.
- If you have recently installed any new software:

  - Uninstalling the new software
  - Reboot
  - Test again
- If that doesn't work, it may have been an update, or some other system change

  - See if you have any recent system restore points
  - Restore back to a restore point and test again

Answer (score 0):

I got it working again, I tried turning off some auto start services, I compared the running services when it was on safe mode vs unsafe mode. I tried turning off non-essential things one by one until it started working again. Ultimately it was a network monitoring tool that came with my motherboard's driver installation disc.

Which is weird because that thing never updated, and I've been using it with no problems for several months. I didn't do any windows/(any)software update for the past week (I casually use my computer everyday). The internet connection just stopped working all of a sudden in the middle of casual browsing. I don't have any auto-updates enabled of any kind (I think).

Regardless. Thanks for all the people giving tips for troubleshooting. Maybe sometime in the future I can use these troubleshooting tips to fix issues I might have or share these with my friends.